# Django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf not returning expected result

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I was applying elastic search in one my django app, Below is my code snippets

documents.py

```
ads_index = Index("ads_index")
ads_index.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=0
)

html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
    char_filter=["html_strip"]
)


@ads_index.doc_type
class AdDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')

    title = fields.TextField(
    analyzer=html_strip,
    fields={
        'title': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
    }
   )

   description = fields.TextField(
    analyzer=html_strip,
    fields={
        'description': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
    }
   )

   category = fields.ObjectField(
    properties={
        'title': fields.TextField(),
    }
)

class Django:
    model = Ad  # The model associated with this Document

    # The fields of the model you want to be indexed in Elasticsearch
    fields = [
        'price',
        'created_at',
    ]

    related_models = [Category]

def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().select_related('category')

def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
    if isinstance(related_instance, Category):
        return related_instance.ad_set.all()
```

serializer

```
class AdDocumentSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        document = AdDocument
        fields = (
            "id",
            "title",
            "description",
            "price",
            "created_at",
        )
```

viewset

```
class AdViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    document = AdDocument
    serializer_class = AdDocumentSerializer
    ordering = ('id',)
    lookup_field = 'id'

    filter_backends = [
        DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
        SuggesterFilterBackend,
    ]

    search_fields = (
        'title',
        'description',
    )

    filter_fields = {
        'id': {
            'field': 'id',
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        },
        'title': 'title.raw',
        'description': 'description.raw',
    }

    ordering_fields = {
        'id': 'id',
    }
```

Below is my data I have

[image: Data]

When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ads/search/?search=Tit` it's not returning anything but when I hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ads/search/?search=a` it's giving me one result.

What's wrong here with my code? Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: the results are correct.. What is your desired output? Do you want an autocompletion for field title and you would expunge stopwords from description field?

Comment: My question is why `search=Tit` is not returning anything?

Comment: because you have set a keyword analyzer on text datatype https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html

Comment: Why to query tit against title field should return something according to you? What kind of configuration are you trying to implement?

Comment: Title field contains `Tit` that's what I am expecting. What should I do to search on both title and description field?

Answer (score 1):

With `keyword` analyzer the entire input string is indicized into inverted index as it is, so you could search only by *exact match*. I use elasticsearch library in python and I don't know very well elasticsearch-dsl. I will try to answer to you using pure elastic configuration, and then you should search how to implement that conf with `elasticsearch-dsl` library in python. If you would search also partial string inside some words, you should indicize them with the `edge-ngram token filter` - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html). With this method you could perform also an autocompletion on search bar, because partial string from the beginning of the word are searchable. You should implement a specific `search_analyzer` because you want that your input query string don't be tokenized with edge-ngram token filter - for an explanation have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html)

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1, 
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": { 
                    "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter" 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

If you don't like this solution because you would also search for partial string in the middle of a word - such as querying for `itl` to retrieve `title` string, you should implement a new `ngram-tokenizer` from scratch - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html):

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. I will try to make another analyzer. Let's see.

Comment: If could help HonzaKral th mainteiner of elasticsearch-dsl library suggests to use suggester method: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/887